# Azure Resource Manager alarm creation

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to use an Azure Resource Manager template to create an alert in Application Insights. The problem I'm having is what value I should put for `resourceUri`. I've tried a few different values, I'm not sure if it's supposed to be the resource I'm monitoring or something else. The documentation is most unhelpful. When I try with the value below it gives me a validation error.

It's also not clear how I actually associate the alert with the component. Is it supposed to be nested as a resource within the component? I have a `dependsOn` referencing the component but from what I understand that would just ensure the other resource gets created first.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
            "name": "testmetrics",
            "location": "Central US"
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Insights/alertrules",
            "name": "testAlert1",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Insights/components/', 'testmetrics')]"
            ],
            "location": "Central US",
            "properties": {
                "description": "Test description",
                "action": {
                    "customEmails": [ "me@somewhere.com" ]
                },
                "condition": {
                    "failedLocationCount": "1",
                    "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.ThresholdRuleCondition",
                    "threshold": "0",
                    "dataSource": {
                        "metricName": "BackupFailed",
                        "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleMetricDataSource",
                        "resourceUri": "/Microsoft.Web/sites/mytestsite"
                    },
                    "operator": "GreaterThan",
                    "windowSize": "1"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. dependsOn is only used to ensure resources will be created first. In you case alert rule should depends on app insights service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great way to figure out how to write these templates correctly (if you can't find a reference in the Github repository for [ARM quickstart templates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates)) is to create a resource group in the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/), configure your system and then export to a JSON template (found in the "Setting" blade when you click your resource group).

I just created an example Application Insights resource with an alert and got the one below.

You can see how the dependency is nested and the correct syntax. Also note that location for Central US is provided as "centralus"

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "alertrules_analertname_name": {
        "defaultValue": "analertname",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "components_appinsightname_name": {
        "defaultValue": "appinsightname",
        "type": "String"
    }
},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/SOME-SUBSCRIPTIN-GUID/resourceGroups/Default-ApplicationInsights-CentralUS/providers/microsoft.insights/alertrules/analertname'.",
        "type": "microsoft.insights/alertrules",
        "name": "[parameters('alertrules_analertname_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
        "location": "East US",
        "tags": {
            "hidden-link:/subscriptions/SOME-SUBSCRIPTIN-GUID/resourcegroups/Default-ApplicationInsights-CentralUS/providers/microsoft.insights/components/appinsightname": "Resource"
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": "[parameters('alertrules_analertname_name')]",
            "description": "Some alert",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "condition": {
                "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.ThresholdRuleCondition",
                "dataSource": {
                    "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleMetricDataSource",
                    "resourceUri": "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', parameters('components_appinsightname_name'))]",
                    "metricName": "availability.availabilityMetric.value"
                },
                "threshold": 1,
                "windowSize": "PT5M"
            },
            "action": {
                "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleEmailAction",
                "customEmails": [
                    "someemail@example.com"
                ]
            }
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', parameters('components_appinsightname_name'))]"
        ]
    },
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/SOME-SUBSCRIPTIN-GUID/resourceGroups/Default-ApplicationInsights-CentralUS/providers/microsoft.insights/components/appinsightname'.",
        "type": "microsoft.insights/components",
        "kind": "web",
        "name": "[parameters('components_appinsightname_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
        "location": "centralus",
        "tags": {},
        "properties": {
            "ApplicationId": "[parameters('components_appinsightname_name')]"
        },
        "dependsOn": []
    }
]
```

}

Hope this helps.

Comment: Definitely helps! This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for but I didn't know where to find it in the portal. I was trying to find it in the Deployment history for the resource group. This will make writing templates a lot easier. Unfortunately it seems like not all resource can be exported this way (e.g. Could not get resources of the type 'Microsoft.Scheduler/jobcollections'. Resources of this type will not be exported. (Code: ExportTemplateProviderError)). But that's a separate issue from this one.

Answer (score 2):

The `resourceUrl` should refer to the Application Insights service in following format:

```
"resourceUri": "[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Insights/components/', 'testmetrics')]"
```

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned I tried that already too. It gives me this error: The target resource id '/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource group>/providers/Microsoft.Insights/components/testmetrics' is not supported. (Code: ResourceNotSupported)

Comment: `Central US` is not valid location for Alert Rule, try to use `East US` instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354057/alert-creation-for-appinsights-fails-with-coderesourcenotsupported/36647495#36647495

Comment: Yes that does seem to be part of the problem. It's weird that the App Insights component would be in one region and the alarms in another.